# Rotated Sorted Array Search

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Suppose a sorted array is rotated at some pivot unknown to you beforehand.

(i.e., 0 1 2 4 5 6 7  might become 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 ).

You are given a target value to search. If found in the array, return its index, otherwise return -1.

You may assume no duplicate exists in the array.

My solution:

```
def search(self, A, B):

    origLength = len(A)

    # arr = []
    # for i in A:
    #     arr.append(i)
    # arr += arr

    i = 0
    j = 2 * len(A) - 2
    while i <= j:
        mid = (i + j) / 2
        if A[(mid % origLength)] == B:
            return mid % origLength
        elif A[mid % origLength] > B:
            j = mid - 1
        else:
            i = mid + 1

    return -1
```

The online judge is telling me that it is wrong. But I don't think it is. My idea is append the two arrays together and do binary search.

Am I wrong?

Comment: can you explain more about what do you mean by rotation?

Comment: I can see where you are coming from by concatenating the arrays, but it would be simpler to just find where the pivot is, determine what section of the array your value would lie in, and then perform a regular binary search using only that segment of the array.

Comment: Also what language is this? It looks like python to me.

Comment: To add to @Matt's comment, there exist a `binarySearch-ey O(logN)` algorithm to find out the pivot in the rotated sorted array. Your overall time complexity would be `O(logN)` only

Comment: @AnandUndavia finding the pivot takes o(logn) and searching after that takes another o(log n) which gives o(log 2n) which is the same as the complexity of concatenating the array? Isn't it? And I don't do the concatenation explicitly, i just use modulo.

Comment: @Matt yes it is python

Comment: Um no, The overall complexity would be `O(logN + logN) = O(2logN) = O(logN)`. And I don't think concatenation takes `logN` time. It should take `O(N)`

Comment: @AnandUndavia i didn't concatenate explicitly (calling A = A+A). What i did was just doing a binary search over 2n items, which means 0(log2n) = o(log2) + o(log n) = o(log n).

Comment: Can you post the link of the online judge? I at once think the same as you: append two array and do something like binary search

Answer (score 0):

Nice try to simulate concatenation, but I think then **the loop condition `i <= j` no longer suffice**.

**And I think there is no workaround for finding the pivot**, thus the attempt is doomed to fail.

Find pivot mean find the smallest element in the possibly rotated sorted array, just as @Matt commented out.

I use your code as below, with a test case, which clearly show it not work.

```
def search(A, B):
    origLength = len(A)
    i = 0
    j = 2 * len(A) - 2
    while i <= j:
        mid = (i + j) / 2
        if A[(mid % origLength)] == B:
            return mid % origLength
        elif A[mid % origLength] > B:
            j = mid - 1
        else:
            i = mid + 1
    return -1

>>> x = [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2]
>>> [search(x,i) for i in range(9)]
[-1, -1, 6, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find `i` such that `a[i] > a[(i+1) % n]` (what the question seems to be calling the "pivot"), then binary search the sub-arrays `a[0..i]` and `a[i+1..n-1]`. So how to find the break point?  Another binary search!  I'll leave the details to you.